# Convert to varbinary

Tags: sql-server

I want to `CONVERT` this

```
40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef
```

to

```
0x40BD001563085FC35165329EA1FF5C5ECBDBBEEF
```

But when I used

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARchar,'40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef')
```

it returns me

```
0x3430626430303135363330383566
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend `'0x'` to it and use [Binary Style 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#binary-styles), e.g.:

```sql
select convert(varbinary(max), '0x' + '40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef', 1)
```

Which returns:

```
(No column name)
0x40BD001563085FC35165329EA1FF5C5ECBDBBEEF
```